Condition on derivatives
I am working with a "well-behaved" optimization problem of the form:
\begin{equation*}
\max_{x} f( g_{1}( x) ,g_{2}( x) ,g_{3}( x) ,\mathbf{y})
\end{equation*}
where $\displaystyle f:\mathbb{R}^{n+3}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continously differentiable, $\displaystyle x\in \mathbb{R}$, $\displaystyle \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ are parameters, and $\displaystyle g_{k} :\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for $\displaystyle k=1,2,3\ $are continuosly differentiable.
I am interested in studying the assumptions I could make on $\displaystyle f$ and $\displaystyle g_{k}$ to study the "comparative statics" of the solution around an optimum. Say that there is a function $\displaystyle x\left(\mathbf{y}^{*}\right) :\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that:
\begin{equation*}
\sum _{k=1}^{3}\frac{\partial f}{\partial g_{k}}\frac{\partial g_{k}}{\partial x}\left( x\left(\mathbf{y}^{*}\right) ,\mathbf{y}^{*}\right) =0
\end{equation*}
I am taking functional assumptions over the $\displaystyle g_{k}$ functions and study their implications, such as:
\begin{gather*}
g_{1}( x) =cy_{1} x-cy_{2} ,\ c\in [ 0,1]\\
g_{2}( x) =( 1-y_{1}) x+y_{2}\\
g_{3}( x) =x
\end{gather*}
The standard problem I am building on takes $\displaystyle c=0$, so I am interested in studying what happens when I increase $\displaystyle c$ around the optimal solution.
I am interested in elasticity notions, for instance:
\begin{equation*}
{\textstyle \epsilon =\frac{dx}{dy_{1}}\left(\mathbf{y}^{*}\right)\frac{1-y_{1}}{x\left(\mathbf{y}^{*}\right)}}
\end{equation*}
Using the Implicit function theorem (I include my derivations below), I find that $\displaystyle \epsilon $ is given by:
\begin{equation*}
{\textstyle \epsilon =-\frac{\frac{1}{x} c\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial g_{1}} -\frac{\partial f}{\partial g_{2}}\right) +cy_{1}\left( c\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{1} \partial g_{1}} -\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{1} \partial g_{2}}\right) +( 1-y_{1})\left( c\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{2} \partial g_{1}} -\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{2} \partial g_{2}}\right) +\left( c\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{3} \partial g_{1}} -\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{3} \partial g_{2}}\right)}{cy_{1}\left[ c\frac{y_{1}}{1-y_{1}}\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{1} \partial g_{1}} +\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{1} \partial g_{2}} +\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{1} \partial g_{3}}\right] +\left[ c\frac{y_{1}}{1-y_{1}}\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{2} \partial g_{1}} +\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{2} \partial g_{2}} +\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{2} \partial g_{3}}\right] +c\frac{y_{1}}{1-y_{1}}\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{3} \partial g_{1}} +\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{3} \partial g_{2}} +\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{3} \partial g_{3}}}}
\end{equation*}
I am looking for conditions that may guarantee an easy characterization of the expression above when we increase $c$.
Clearly, differentiating the expression above with respect to $\displaystyle c$ yields a messy expression, especially due to the emergence of third order derivatives.
Here are ny thoughts:

The first-order effect given by $\frac{1}{x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial g_{1}}$ should dominate in most solutions, meaning that the derivative should have the sign of -$\frac{1}{x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial g_{1}}$

Second-order effects may matter for high values of $\displaystyle c$ (this is clear for $\displaystyle c\rightarrow \infty $), but this should not be \ a concern since I assume $\displaystyle c\leq 1$.


This means that in order for the first-order effect to be dominant I need a conition on the derivatives of my $\displaystyle f$ function. My intuition is that I need something like $\displaystyle f^{( n)}$ to be decrasing in $\displaystyle n$.
Clearly, there are some "nice" functions that do the trick, especially those in which the second-order derivative of $\displaystyle g_{1}$ is zero, but I was wondering if there could be a more general alternative.

Derivations
I can approach this by applying the implicit function theorem, I know that I can study the function:
\begin{equation*}
F( x,\mathbf{y}) =\sum _{k=1}^{3}\frac{\partial f}{\partial g_{k}}\frac{\partial g_{k}}{\partial x}( g_{1}( x) ,g_{2}( x) ,g_{3}( x) ,\mathbf{y}) =cy_{1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial g_{1}} +( 1-y_{1})\frac{\partial f}{\partial g_{2}} +\frac{\partial f}{\partial g_{3}} =0
\end{equation*}
And that if, for $\displaystyle \mathbf{y}^{*}$ such that $\displaystyle x\left(\mathbf{y}^{*}\right) =x^{*}$, and if $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\left( x^{*} ,\mathbf{y}^{*}\right) \neq 0$, then
\begin{equation*}
\frac{dx}{dy_{1}}\left(\mathbf{y}^{*}\right) =-\frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial y_{1}} [x(\mathbf{y}^{*} );\mathbf{y}^{*} ]}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} [x(\mathbf{y}^{*} );\mathbf{y}^{*} ]} =-\frac{\sum _{k=1}^{3}\left[\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{k} \partial y_{1}}\frac{\partial g_{k}}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial f}{\partial g_{k}}\frac{\partial ^{2} g_{k}}{\partial x\partial y_{1}}\right]\left( x^{*} ,\mathbf{y}^{*}\right)}{\sum _{k=1}^{3}\left[\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{k} \partial x}\frac{\partial g_{k}}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial f}{\partial g_{k}}\frac{\partial ^{2} g_{k}}{\partial x^{2}}\right]\left( x^{*} ,\mathbf{y}^{*}\right)}
\end{equation*}
In this case:
\begin{gather*}
{\textstyle \frac{d\ F}{d\ y_{1}} =c\frac{\partial f}{\partial g_{1}} -\frac{\partial f}{\partial g_{2}} +cy_{1}\left( cx\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{1} \partial g_{1}} -x\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{1} \partial g_{2}}\right) +( 1-y_{1})\left( cx\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{2} \partial g_{1}} -x\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{2} \partial g_{2}}\right) +\left( cx\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{3} \partial g_{1}} -x\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{3} \partial g_{2}}\right)}\\
\end{gather*}
\begin{gather}
{\textstyle \frac{d\ F}{d\ x} =cy_{1}\left[ cy_{1}\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{1} \partial g_{1}} +( 1-y_{1})\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{1} \partial g_{2}} +\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{1} \partial g_{3}}\right]}\\
{\textstyle +( 1-y_{1})\left[ cy_{1}\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{2} \partial g_{1}} +( 1-y_{1})\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{2} \partial g_{2}} +\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{2} \partial g_{3}}\right] +cy_{1}\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{3} \partial g_{1}} +( 1-y_{1})\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{3} \partial g_{2}} +\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{3} \partial g_{3}}} \notag
\end{gather}
And:
\begin{equation*}
{\textstyle \frac{dx}{dy_{1}}\left(\mathbf{y}^{*}\right) =-\frac{c\frac{\partial f}{\partial g_{1}} -\frac{\partial f}{\partial g_{2}} +cy_{1}\left( cx\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{1} \partial g_{1}} -x\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{1} \partial g_{2}}\right) +( 1-y_{1})\left( cx\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{2} \partial g_{1}} -x\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{2} \partial g_{2}}\right) +\left( cx\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{3} \partial g_{1}} -x\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{3} \partial g_{2}}\right)}{{\textstyle cy_{1}\left[ cy_{1}\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{1} \partial g_{1}} +( 1-y_{1})\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{1} \partial g_{2}} +\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{1} \partial g_{3}}\right] +( 1-y_{1})\left[ cy_{1}\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{2} \partial g_{1}} +( 1-y_{1})\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{2} \partial g_{2}} +\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{2} \partial g_{3}}\right] +cy_{1}\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{3} \partial g_{1}} +( 1-y_{1})\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{3} \partial g_{2}} +\frac{\partial ^{2} f}{\partial g_{3} \partial g_{3}}}}}
\end{equation*}

You are right, thanks!
